# Local variable destructor not invoked in thread routine function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I wrote simple code with vs2013 and it works odd:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <tchar.h>

class A
{
public:
    explicit A(uint8_t byte) : mByte(byte) {}
    ~A() { _tprintf(_T("A::~A(%x)\n"), mByte); }
private:
    uint8_t mByte;
};

unsigned WINAPI threadRoutine(void*)
{
    A a0(0x41);
    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, threadRoutine, NULL, 0, NULL);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    return 0;
}
```

Output is empty, so it means A-dtor was not invoked for local variable a0?

Is there some bug inside my code?

How to maintain RAII inside thread routine function if local variable destructor not invoked after function returns?

Comment: You don't need to call `_endthreadex()` explicitly. Just let the function terminate normally.

Comment: I suggest you use `std::thread` instead of compiler specific methods.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! I did not read _endthreadex manual carefully!!!

Comment: @AndyProwl You should make that an answer.

Comment: @BartvanNierop: You're right, maybe, but I don't have time to craft a well-written answer with all the necessary info. I don't know much about `_endthreadex()` apart from knowing it's not necessary. For instance, I don't know why it does not cause destructors of local variables to be invoked. I just suspected it doesn't do that and suggested to eliminate it. Enough for a comment, but not for an answer - at least IMO.

Comment: Added an answer because comments are not meant to be permanent -- this way someone looking at this question might find the answer. If you change your mind, I'll be happy to remove my answer.

Comment: @Andy Prowl, well as for me, I'm just glad I know now how to maintain raii with _beginthreadex, answer or comment no matter, thank you;) p.s.: I should read manuals more carefully!

Comment: @kvv At the least, you should definitely re-read the manual before posting on SO.

Comment: @Andy If you don't have time to write an answer then don't write an answer (why, then, are you even here?!), but writing the solution in a comment just breaks everything -.-

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I didn't even know that would answer the question.

Comment: @Andew I will re-read twise next time, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_endthread` and `_endthreadex` are called automatically after a thread returns from the routine passed to `_beginthread` or `_beginthreadex`.

You *can* call them explicitly to end a thread, but you don't have to.

Calls to `_endthread` and `_endthreadex` cause pending C++ destructors on the thread they terminate not to be called.

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw264s73.aspx)